# table checkbox in laravel delete multiple data with foreign key error

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5.4, sql-delete

i have a checkbox list of products and i want to delete all the data and also from its foreign key in other table using checkbox.

Here is what i've got, from my table i created a form that is being routed to delete data that is checked from the checkbox.

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.delproducts') }}" method="get" id="delprod">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <table class="table table-hover">                                    
        <thead>                        
            <tr>
              <th width="4%"></th>
              <th width="17%">SUB-CATEGORY</th>
              <th width="30%">PRODUCT NAME</th>
              <th width="10%">QTY</th>
              <th width="10%">STATUS</th>
              <th width="25%">UPDATED</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @foreach($products as $key => $data)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{ $data->product_id }}" />&nbsp;</td>                            
                <td><a href="#"> {{ $data->name }} </a></td>
                <td><a href="#"> {{ $data->product_name }} </a></td>
                <td><a href="#"> {{ $data->quantity }} </a></td>
                <td><a href="#"> {{ $data->status }} </a></td>
                <td>{{ $data->updated_at }}</td>                            
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
<p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right delbtn" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p>
```

ive made my button outside the form but i have created a javascript for it.

```
$(".delbtn").click( function() {
    $('#delprod').submit();
});
```

in my controller here is what i did:

```
public function deleteProducts(Request $request) {

    Product::destroy($request->products);

    return redirect()->route('admin.product');
}
```

i got an error because this Product table has a foreign key from table `Product_image` how can i also make a controller to delete all data in my  `Product_image` table that has `product_id` that is being checked in checkbox?

i tried to make a model `Product_image` and tried this in my controller

```
Product_image::destroy($request->products);
```

but it gives me error because it says it does't exist. Any suggestions in making a query to delete a foreign key that is being passed by checkbox? . something like deleting a query that accepts array from checkbox.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a relation between Product Image you can do this. (I assume your relation name is `productImage`. Laravel **destroy** function does not removes relationships. If you didnt define `onDelete('cascade')`

If you want to delete relations you need to define onDelete on your migration file or in database directly.

```
  $table
    ->foreign('product_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('product_image')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

After that you can try using destroy (not sure if it removes relationships) if its not then you can do this

```
public function deleteProducts(Request $request) {
    foreach ($request->products as $product_id) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->productImage()->delete();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.product');
}
```

If no relation than you need to remove relational data manually.

Comment: Hello sir thanks for your answer. I don't have relation in my product to product image. Can it be possible to manually delete?

Comment: you need to manual database query for that... I would say simply create relationship

Comment: hello sir i got undefined variable table. i made like this: public function deleteProducts(Request $request) {
        foreach ($request->products as $product_id) {
        $table->foreign('product_id')
        ->references('product_id')
        ->on('product_images')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        }

        Product::destroy($request->products);
        return redirect()->route('admin.product');
    }